# bind traffic from selenium_webdriver(chrome) to specific network interface/tunnel

Tags: python, linux, selenium, webdriver, network-interface

task is to automate some browser activity via specific network interface(at linux).
since I need to initiate video on page- I pick selenium(python) and made all the routine to make video play using selenium, but application goes through default interface.
question- how to force chrome to use for example tun0?
note: I've seen similar question/answers, but wasn't able to solve my problem, due to lack of linux programming experience. if possible provide step by step guide, thank you.

Comment: I found [solution] (https://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html) to make web-browser to use specific IP.-BIND_ADDR=10.254.64.21 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/bind.so firefox , that command starts new instance of FF and it uses specific net_iface

however, I can't link it to webdriver, i.e to start as a part of selenium code-driver = webdriver.Chrome() which is also initiate web-broser, that uses defaul net_iface.
QUESTION- how to make those two commands work together?

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work for Firefox, I followed https://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html to create /usr/lib/bind.so

I then hacked /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py to the following:

```
#self._firefox_env['LD_PRELOAD'] = self.NO_FOCUS_LIBRARY_NAME
self._firefox_env['LD_PRELOAD'] = "/usr/lib/bind.so"
self._firefox_env['BIND_ADDR'] = "198.58.118.236"
```

The line commented out was the original line.

For Chrome, it looks like you would hack `self.env = env` in service.py